# Lost in WSDL web service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi im doing a billing system for a page. i need to echo a image, *ISO/IEC 18004:2000, (PDF?)*

Wich is generated using this format:

```
?re=XAXX010101000&rr=XAXX010101000&tt=1234567890.123456&id=ad662d33-6934-459c-a128-

BDf0393f0f44
```

They have give me an URL:

```
www.url.com/webservice/webservice/server32_salesPartner.php?wsdl
```

Url.com is to hide the real wsdl any, way, i have read here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_introduction.htm

And other stuff.. But I can't figure out how to *"send"* the info, i know info is not really sent, but here is where i get lost

Do i have to build a URL after `server32_salesPartner.php?`?, how?

Like this:

```
www.url.com/webservice/webservice/server32_salesPartner.php?re=XAXX010101000&rr=XAXX010101000&tt=1234567890.123456&id=ad662d33-6934-459c-a128-

BDf0393f0f44
```

How do i get the image then? I'm lost here.

i ask here cause the web service provider is really bad, lazy and i have been waiting for an answer for 3 days, and need to move on faster on this.

Sorry im really newbie at wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a soap service with rest. That won't work. Check if there is any framework for php that read the wsdl and creates a client for you. The other way is to write this client by yourself and call the SOAP with appropriate SOAP protocol.

Comment: thanks i just found out the same stuff, but im still lost , http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Just create the client with this call SoapClient::SoapClient ( "your wsdl address"), i dont know how to compile and run it in php but maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: yeah thats exactly the kind of help im looking for, just some one can point me in the right direction to compile en echo the image.